# How do I transfer app data/settings from Samsung Galaxy S3 to Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have Samsung Galaxy S3 on Android 4.1 and Samsung Galaxy S6 on Android 5.0. When I turned on the Samsung Galaxy S6 for the first time, it said by using NFC, it would transfer all my info.  I don't know if I did it wrong, but all the apps on my new Samsung Galaxy S6 are empty. The settings and levels completed in games do not appear on the Samsung Galaxy S6.

Is there any easy way to transfer *everything* from my Samsung Galaxy S3 to Samsung Galaxy S6? I don't have access to a PC. My Samsung Galaxy S3 is rooted if that helps with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Samsung Galaxy S3 is rooted. You could make app backups with a 3rd-party app, such as Titanium Backup, but to use Titanium Backup to restore them on your Samsung Galaxy S6, it would need to be rooted as well.

I know Google claims that its backup service saves app data and settings as well. But I think that only works if the app dev has added the option to store things in the cloud.

Personally, I can say that TB works like a charm for me. For non-rooted options (I assume your Samsung Galaxy S6 isn't rooted if you don't have access to a PC). It looks like [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup.license) can back up to the cloud. The only reason I linked the paid one is because the free one doesn't allow you to back up to the cloud.

Comment: I can't root my S6 for sure. No computer and towelroot doesn't work. That's how easy it has to be for me.

Comment: Did you give the app I linked a try? Assuming you have a payment option, there is that window that google gives you to refund the app if you don't like it.